# three20 - loading external Data for TTViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, three20

i created a TTViewController that should show some Informations from a external (web) source.
i already worked with some TTableViewControllers where i used the TTModel System (i created a TTURLRequestModel and a TTListDataSource for my TTTableViewControllers)

whats the way to do this with a TTViewController?
is there also something like a DataSource and Request Model or do i have to assign my ViewController with the TTURLRequestDelegate and run a simple URL Request?

im asking because i dont know whats the "best" and "newest" way to fill my viewcontroller with data from the web. i know how to do this for tableviews but not for views.

thanks in advance

edit: some code

my singlePostViewController:

```
@interface singlePostViewController : TTModelViewController 
       singlePostModel *_singlepostmodel; 
@end 
- (void) createModel { 
        _singlepostmodel = [[singlePostModel alloc] init]; 
}
```

and my singlePostModel

```
@interface singlePostModel : TTURLRequestModel { 
} 

@end
```

but what to do now? where to load my stuff and setting it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [TTModelViewController](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_model_view_controller.html) class. You'll want to subclass that. You create the TTURLRequestModel in the [createModel:](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_model_view_controller.html#a277731e4a0b2afacef0f50d052f5a6ee) method and add "self" to the list of model's delegates. There are a bunch of interesting methods available that should be sufficient for what you're trying to do.

In particular, [this PDF](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/web/TTModel%20ecosystem.pdf) shows a good relationship between the model, datasource, and controller classes.

Comment: hm have you something like an example for that, or a tutorial?

Comment: Added a link to a useful PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Check this twitter example
https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/samples/TTTwitter
Its straightforward example.

You need to override "-(void) load:(TTURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy more:(BOOL)more" method in your subclass of TTURLRequestModel to fetch remote data.